# Login Angular Authentication

Tags: angular, angular5

Saludos Tengo un login ya conectado a la api con token pero al ingresar no hace el envio a la pagina home

Este es el codigo : USER.service.ts

```
userAuthentication(username,password){
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password)
  })
};
var data = 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password);
var reqHeader = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-urlencoded'});
reqHeader.append('Authorization', data);
return this.http.post(this.rootUrl + '/Auth  ','',httpOptions);
 }
```

CODIGO  de SIGNIN :

```
OnSubmit(username,password){

    this.userService.userAuthentication(username,password).subscribe((data: any)=> {
      alert(data);
      localStorage.setItem('token', data.access_token );
      this.router.navigate['/home'];

    },
    (err : HttpErrorResponse)=>{
        this.isLoginError = true;

    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenés un error en tu SIGNIN:
`this.router.navigate['/home'];` tiene que ser `this.router.navigate(['/home']);`

Te faltaron los paréntesis, que indican una llamada a una función.
Si usas solo los brakets `[]` (en Javascript) estás extrayendo una propiedad de un objeto. En este caso `navigate` no contiene ninguna propiedad `/home`, pero como no estás haciendo nada con ello, no lanza error.
Si haces `console.log(this.router.navigate['/home'])` en tu consola aparecerá: `undefined`.

Comment: Gracias bro me funciono